# How to use placeholders with @Email hibernate validator

Tags: spring-mvc, validation, hibernate-validator

By default `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email` shows `not a well-formed email address` but I want to show `foo is not a well-formed email address` if the user enters just `foo` where an well formatted email is required. So I need to have a placeholder for `foo`. The property in my domain object is annotated with `@Email`.

I have `Email = {0} is not a well-formed email address` in my resource bundle file which shows `email is not a well-formed email address` when the user enters `foo` for the email field.

Is it possible to generate that entered value and display it for the error message?

I am using Hibernate 3.5 with Spring MVC 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Hibernate Validator as your Bean Validation Provider, you can use the `ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator` introduced in release 4.2. To do so just set that interpolator when retrieving your `Validator`, e.g. like this:

```
Configuration<?> configuration = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure();

Validator validator = configuration
    .messageInterpolator(new ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator(
        configuration.getDefaultMessageInterpolator()))
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();
```

Using that interpolator you can refer to the validated value by the placeholder `{validatedValue}` from within the error message: `{validatedValue} is not a well-formed email address`.

You can find out more in the HV [reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-message-interpolator).

Comment: @Gunner: I am using Hibernate 3.5. Could the same not be achieved in Hibernate 3.5? I used `@Email` at my `private String email;` to validate that field. Thanks for the reply. I'll be looking into it.

Comment: So how is validation triggered in your case? Automatically upon persisting entities as defined by JPA 2? In that case the default validator factory is used to obtain the validator which can be configured by using the file `META-INF/validation.xml`. See the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html#d0e2053) for an example which also shows how to set a specific message interpolator such as `ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator`.

Comment: @Gunner: Yes, validation triggers while persisting entities.

Comment: Then should configuring the interpolator using `META-INF/validation.xml` as described above do the trick.

Comment: @Gunner: I will surely be doing that. It's just that I am not a Hibernate Pro and it might take sometime for me to do that and I've got myself in the middle of another task. So for now I've kept things simple and have set a static "This is not a well-formed email" error message for now. I will post my answer once I do that. Many thanks for your guidance :)